# How to create Login/Register page in ASP MVC without EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a register and login Page in ASP MVC without EF.

I wrote this solution but I recieve always error that "connection" and "command" does not exist in the current context :

```
public ActionResult Login(Client cmodel)

    public string GetPassword(string email)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deliverycon"]))
        {
            using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 password from clients where email=@email", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    return reader["password"].ToString;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're missing "var", try var connection, var command and var reader

Comment: You need to declare then - SqlConnection connection and then SqlCommand command and finally SqlDataReader read

Comment: thank you guys ! but the problem I cannot convert reader to string

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code.  Wherever you copied/pasted this from isn't a reliable source of working code.  I imagine the compiler is giving you a variety of syntax and type errors here.

Comment: I don't miss ADO.NET. That's like 1 line in EF (with IoC) and no magic strings.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ or https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Comment: @SteveGreene thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you must declare your variables before you assign to them, even within a `using` statement. You have basically done the equivalent of this:

```
myValue = 10;
```

The compiler will complain that `myValue` doesn't exist in the current context. The solution is to declare the variable and then assign it, which you can do with a single line of code:

```
int myValue = 10;
```

You never actually declared your variables for `connection` or `command` or `reader`. You need to declare them as a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`, or you can [use the implicit `var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

This example shows both types:

```
public string GetPassword(string email)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deliverycon"]))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 password from clients where email=@email", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                return reader["password"].ToString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`var` is often used when the type is clear from the context, while explicitly saying the type is often used when it's unclear.

Also, you appear to be storing your password in plaintext in your database. This is a terrible idea. Passwords should be one-way hashed and salted. It is not a good idea to roll your own security system if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Exact Updated to fix it with reader as well, though I'd have hoped you could have figured it out from the fix on the connection and command.

Comment: ah ok ! do you have a good tuto or idea to make that because I searched over all internet and I found nothing without EF

Comment: @Exact Stack Overflow is not here to find tutorials for you.

Comment: that was only a question ! Not necessary to be rude ! I asked you if you have an idea or no because I searched it and I found only with EF !

Comment: @Exact I'm not sure how you interpreted that to be rude. I am simply stating that [Stack Overflow is not here to find tutorials for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ah ok sorry ! Just wasn't linked in your previous comment so I understand it wrong ! anyway thank you for your help and I will try to learn more about ASP MVC :)